# Openshift - liveness probe not working for http

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, probe

I have configured liveness probe using httpGet but it's failing with `*error Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers*`

But the same API is working fine inside the container(using curl) and outside the container(postman). 
I have tried adding host attribute in liveness probe but no luck.

Any idea what's going wrong.

Liveness Probe:

```
 livenessProbe:
        initialDelaySeconds: 45
        periodSeconds: 10
        httpGet:
           path: /health
           port: xxxxx
        timeoutSeconds: 5
```

**Version details:**

```
OpenShift Master->v3.9.0+ba7faec-1
Kubernetes Master->v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
OpenShift Web Console->v3.9.0+b600d46-dirty
```

Comment: Do you see the request in your app's logs?

Comment: Are you passing custom header in the request while trying from outside?

Comment: @Sudhir am not passing any headers while executing from outside.

Comment: @coderanger I didn't check the logs. will check.

Comment: Have you exposed the port with a service?

Comment: @Crou Yes exposed via Service and Route.

Comment: Try adding headers like in [this example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/pods/probe/http-liveness.yaml)

Comment: I found that there was a problem with /helath API. After fixing the problem liveness probe is worked fine. Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the `initialDelaySeconds`, port lower, and check for any transitive features (such as PVC) causing slow loading:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 200
  timeoutSeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 5
```

PS: For success on probe validation your HTTP return status must be greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400.

Hope this helps

Comment: What does ‘port lower’ mean?

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for review, in the last pod security settings what i saw the high ports were locked by default, it is not a rule